# Counting number of swaps and comparisons in selection sort

Tags: c++, sorting

I am trying to count the number of swaps and comparisons in selection sort.
Array = [7, -9, -2, 17, 19, 12, 8,  1, -20, 15, 3, 5].

```
void main()
{

    int size = 12, arr[] = { 7, - 9, - 2,   17, 19, 12, 8,  1, - 20,    15, 3,    5 };
    int i, j, temp;
    int comparison = 0;
    int swaps = 0;

    std::cout << "Unsorted: ";
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        std::cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }

    std::cout << "\n";

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (j = i + 1; j < size; j++)
        {
            comparison = comparison + 1;
            if (arr[i] > arr[j])
            {
                swaps = swaps + 1;
                temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    std::cout << "\nComparisons: " << comparison;
    std::cout << "\nSwap: " << swaps;

    std::cout << "\n\nSorted: ";
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        std::cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
```

This returns 66 comparisons and 34 swaps. How do you count and output the number of comparisons and swaps correctly?

Comment: Is there a problem with the numbers you get? What did you expect them to be?

Comment: Your shown code seems show that already. What is  your issue ?

Comment: ***How do you count and output the number of comparisons and swaps correctly*** I also think you are already doing that. If you don't trust the result try  a few sorts of 3 numbers on paper and see if you get the same results.

Answer (score -1):

On this awesome website http://bigocheatsheet.com/ you can find the Order for all different sorting algorithms. It says that selection sort should have a worst case of O(n^2). You've got 12 variables; 12^2 = 144, which is way larger than the number of swaps and comparisons you've got -- so you're well within the worst case range.

However, if you're saying you want to *output* the swaps that are made, and not the actual number of swaps, you can write something like:

```
if (arr[i] > arr[j])
{
    std::cout << "Swapping " << arr[i] << " with " << arr[j] << ".\n";
    swaps = swaps + 1;
    temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = temp;
}
```

Comment: This is not the way big O notation works. You can get a number that's larger than n^2 for a specific value of n and still be O(n^2) worst case.